# Writing list of feature classes with fields to one csv file per feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, csv, python-2.7

I have a database with multiple feature classes. Now I extracted a list of feature classes and a list of fields. I figured out how to write the list of feature classes and the corresponding fields to csv. But the csv file gets really long. Instead I would like to write each feature class name with the corresponding field names to a separate csv file. 
My code looks like this right now:

```
def csvwriter (csvfile, mylist):
    myfile = open(csvfile,'ab')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(mylist)

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()
for ds in datasets:
    dslist = []
    dslist.append(ds)
    csvwriter (csvfile1,dslist)
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",ds):
        fclist = []
        fclist.append(fc)
        csvwriter(csvfile1,fclist)
        for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc):
            fieldlist = []
            fieldlist.append(field.name)
            csvwriter(csvfile1,fieldlist)
```

Comment: You'll need to change the CSV file name to a variable that depends on the feature class, either changing based on an index value (e.g. 1, 2, 3) or based on the feature class name.

Comment: @Erica Thanks, that gave me a push in the right direction. I got it to work.

Comment: OK great -- I was just working up a little script to test it myself, but I'll stop now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the same `csvfile1` each time, define a variable that depends on the feature class name. For example:

```
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
    csvFileName = 'CSV_{}.csv'.format(fc) # or just = fc + '.csv'
    for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc):
        csvwriter(csvFileName,field.name)
```